# How to listen if AutoCompleteTextView full suggestion word is typed

Tags: java, android, listener, actionlistener, autocompletetextview

I want my fragment to listen if that full suggestion word of the AutoCompleteAdapter list is typed.

For example, my list contains these elements:

```
{"Alireza Noorali", "Armin Yaghini", "Hassan Mirfendereski"}
```

The user is typing `Alireza Nooral` in AutoCompleteTextView, I want to `dismissDropDown()` and do something else when user typed the last character of suggestion which is `i` to be `Alireza Noorali`.

I implemented a Custom Adapter and in its getFilter method put a listener:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return nameFilter;
}

/*
 * Custom Filter implementation for custom suggestions we provide.
 */
private Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence inputChars) {

        if (inputChars != null) {

            try {
                suggestions.clear();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (String acTvItem : tempItems) {
                if (acTvItem.toLowerCase().contains(inputChars.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    suggestions.add(acTvItem);
                }

                if (listener != null && acTvItem.equalsIgnoreCase(inputChars.toString()) && results.count == 1) {
                    listener.onCompleteInputListener(key);
                }
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        List<String> filterList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        if (results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            if (filterList != null && !filterList.isEmpty()) {
                for (String acTvItem : filterList) {
                    add(acTvItem);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};


/*  ---------- Interface ----------  */

public interface CompleteInputListener {
    void onCompleteInputListener(String key);
}
```

In my fragment I implemented listener method:

```
private AcTvAdapter.CompleteInputListener completeInputListener() {
    return new AcTvAdapter.CompleteInputListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleteInputListener(String key) {

            // hideSoftKeyboard & dismissDropDown & something else
        }
    };
}
```

But when I do the initially said scenario, I get this warning:

```
W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7809)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1338)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5446)
    at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:14749)
    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:14713)
    at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:12542)
    at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:8611)
    at ir.noorali.myapp.MyFrag.getCountry(MyFrag.java:662)
    at ir.noorali.myapp.MyFrag$12.onCompleteInputListener(MyFrag.java:995)
    at ir.noorali.myapp.adapters.AcTvAdapter$1.performFiltering(AcTvAdapter.java:120)
    at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I Know the reason is the declaration of ActionListener:

> Java ActionListener is an invisible **GUI object** that gets its method called when the user performs a certain action. Common actions include pressing the push button, toggling the toggle button, checking the checkbox, selecting an item in combo box and the like.

but I have no idea about how to achieve my purpose. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: `publishResults` is called on UI thread - so call your `onCompleteInputListener` there

Comment: It works like a charm! thank you!

Comment: good, you are welcome

Comment: how about `yourList.contains("Alireza Nooral")` ?

Comment: @SHAHMDMONIRULISLAM Thank you for your important point that you said. I edited my post and I added `results.count == 1` in `if` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pskink said in comments, I called `onCompleteInputListener` on `publishResults` and the problem solved. This is my new code:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return nameFilter;
}

/*
 * Custom Filter implementation for custom suggestions we provide.
 */
private Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence inputChars) {

        if (inputChars != null) {

            try {
                suggestions.clear();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (String acTvItem : tempItems) {
                if (acTvItem.toLowerCase().contains(inputChars.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    suggestions.add(acTvItem);
                }
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        List<String> filterList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        if (results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            if (filterList != null && !filterList.isEmpty()) {

                for (String acTvItem : filterList) {

                if (listener != null && acTvItem.equalsIgnoreCase(inputChars.toString()) && results.count == 1) {
                    listener.onCompleteInputListener(key);
                }

                    add(acTvItem);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};


/*  ---------- Interface ----------  */

public interface CompleteInputListener {
    void onCompleteInputListener(String key);
}
```

Now it works without any warning!